# React Web App launched from iOS homescreen weird behavior

Tags: ios, reactjs, single-page-application, react-router-v4

I am using the following Meta tag:

`<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">`:

If I add app to homescreen from its root route `"/"`. the app launches fine and if I click on `NavLinks` that lead to other routes in the app the new route open in the `safari` browser with the address bar instead of staying in the `standalone` mode.

Additionally:  If I add the app to homescreen while i'm on a non-root route i.e `"/aboutUs"` then If I try to launch the app from homescreen the app launches to a blank white screen.

If I remove the meta tag above, the app works as it should.

Comment: Hi. Did you find an answer to this? I can't it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you just use attribute 'href' and '_blank' in 'a' tag, you will open new tab in browser. If you use `window.open(url, '_blank');`, you new page will be in standalone mode. Hope this will help you.